# iPhone - Pulling text from a NSURL

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsurl, text-parsing

Hey guys, I am working on an application that initially loads a website from the URL http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/::Random? which gives me a random wikipedia page. I was wondering how would I go about parsing the URL to get the actual page label? Like I know that the page for the United States is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States and Mighty Morphin Power Rangers (the original of course) is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Morphin_Power_Rangers

How do I go about dealing with the multiple underscores (a random variable) in the URL?

Comment: Sorry, Could not get you ...What you want to do with NSURL ?

Comment: I just want to know what page I am on..and it only applies to wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the case of your Wikipedia URL, you can use the `lastComponent` method of `NSURL` combined with some `NSString` replacement. Here's an example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom"];
NSString *title = [url lastPathComponent];
title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
```

So what happens is you create a `NSURL`, you ask it for the last component which is returned as a string ("United_Kingdom"), and then you replace all underscores in the string with spaces (giving you "United Kingdom").